# what follow "look like"?

Tags: grammar

today i stumbled upon 2 different sources of information

1. [like/as though/as if](http://www.grammarerrors.com/grammar/likeas-thoughas-if/)
2. [look, seem and appear](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv353.shtml)

and these got me confused, because look like + clause sounds so natural to me and bbc has always been my favorite page for learning english.Howerver as a true learner i simply cannot turn a blind eye to a piece of information because it's unpopular.

So, the bottom line question is : is it possible to have a clause following the look like structure? EX "It looks like it will rain" .

Comment: Your first link (to grammarerrors.com) is just outdated/pedantic tosh. Ignore it. If [it looks like you need](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+looks+like+you+need%22) convincing, look at an estimated 12,000 written instances in that link.

Comment: I'd never heard of a rule that you can't use a clause after "look like" - certainly it's very common to do so. So it looks like I'm agreeing with the BBC.

Comment: I'm familiar with that rule.  I've seen it in the *style guides* of last century.  The problem with publishing grammar, usage and style all under the same cover is that a number of students never learn to distinguish between the three.  For example, the same guides might recommend "among the three" over "between the three" -- where *no* difference in grammar exists.

Comment: I just find something like this http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/look

And it state that it look like can be follow by noun phrase but they do not include a simple clause case.So is the whole  "a clause can follow  it look like" thing is just too common for it to list or something's missing here.

I've been using this dictionary as a source of reference lately, it's crecible right?

Comment: A similar point is made by https://bigwords101.com/2013/uncategorized/winstons-taste-good-like-as-a-cigarette-should/ and this was widely considered a "rule" of grammar through the 1960s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_tastes_good_like_a_cigarette_should mentions the uproar when the descriptivist Webster's 3rd edition refused to condemn this usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in the context of

> it **seems as though** it will rain

or

> it **appears** it will rain

Then absolutely you can say, "It looks like it will rain".  I don't know where the "grammar errors" site is getting its information, but (at least in American English) this is used all the time.

> She **looks like** she's about ten years old.
>
> It **looks like** there are going to be a lot of people at the conference.
>
> It **looks like** that site is offering grammar "rules" without sources to back them up.

Comment: i knew something was off with that site cause i've been hearing "it looks like it's gonna rain"  my whole life.Imagine knowing for sure that 1+1=2 and someone comes in and says otherwise.Thanks for you clarification gents/ladies.

P/S: is it safe to assume that bbc is a good and reliable source of english material ?